# birds and cages

Tags: puzzle

We have a number of birds and  we bought cages to put them in. If we put $7$ birds in each cage then one bird is left over. If we put $9$ birds in each cage then one cage is left over. Find the number of birds and cages.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: $5$? aM I wrong?

Comment: The modulo solution is too complicated and incorrect?! It would suggest that C = 12 is also a solution. Just $7C  + 1 = 9(C-1)$ already gives $C = 5$.

Comment: we have 2 solutions?

Comment: Let $x$ = number of cages. Then $7x+1=9(x-1)$ so $x=5$ cages is correct, as you commented.

Comment: Also $1$ bird and $100000$ cages is formally correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B$ is the number of birds, and $C$ is the number of cages, we have the following:
$$9(C-1) = B\ ;\ \ 7C + 1 = B$$
You can quickly reduce this to find that $\dots$